# Some help needed chaining two request-promises together in node.js

Tags: node.js, request, discord, request-promise

I'm helping out with a Discord bot and am using node.js. I need to get results from two separate json feeds and am using request-promise for it.

```
tableRequest().then(function(val) {
                console.log(val);
            }).catch(function(err) {
                console.err("Something went wrong");
            });

playersRequest().then(function(val) {
                console.log(val);
            }).catch(function(err) {
                console.err("Something went wrong");
            });
```

The top of each function looks like this.

```
function tableRequest(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        request('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/table', function (error, response, body) {
```

When I run my code, both sets of data are logged to the console fine, but from what I've read, this isn't really right. And how do I then use the two `val` elsewhere?

This isn't my forte whatsoever.. I'm a Drupal guy. Thanks if you can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will recommend you to use ES7 [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

The code will then become:

```
async function myFunction() {
   let val_1 = await tableRequest();
   let val_2 = await playersRequest()
   return {val_1, val_2}; // This way you could use the values 
   // inside another function
}
```

If you still have to use promises, you could use [bluebird library](http://bluebirdjs.com/). Using bluebird's promise, you could have:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');

Promise.coroutine(function*() {
   let val_1 = yield tableRequest();
   let val_2 = yield playersRequest();
   // Now you could use the values
})
```

If, you don't want to use either of `async/await` or `bluebird`, you could chain like this:

```
let val_1, val_2;
tableRequest().then(val => {
    val_1 = val;
    // Do something and return
    return foo;
})
.then(foo => playersRequest())
.then(val => {
    val_2 = val;
 })
 .catch(e => console.log(e))
```

Comment: Wow, I've looked at so many answer and was confused so much.. I'll try these in around 30 minutes and hopefully have some success. It looks good.

Comment: @NiallMurphy Also added the chaining logic

Comment: I had to update my version of node but finally got the async/await working perfectly with your code. Thank you!